# Spring Data JPA save method effectiveness in Java 8 functional map

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-8, spring-data-jpa

When using Spring Data together with Java 8 we have two options to save the collection:

1. We can use classic `List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities)` method that takes the whole list.
   Example:

   ```
   someOtherRepository.save(
       someRepository.findAll()
       .stream()
       .map(something -> {
           //some operations
           return someOtherThing;
       })
       .collect(Collectors.toList())
   );
   ```
2. We can use `S save(S entity)` method that takes single entity and use it in a `stream` in a `map`.
   Example:

   ```
   someRepository.findAll()
   .stream()
   .map(something -> {
       //some operations
       return someOtherThing;
   })
   .map(someOtherRepository::save)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

The question is:
Is there a difference in execution time between those two approaches? If yes which is more effective (faster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save(Iterable<S> entities)` relies on iterating and invoking `save(S entity)` :

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {

    List<S> result = new ArrayList<S>();

    if (entities == null) {
        return result;
    }

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}
```

So the two should give the same result in terms of performance.

To do batch insert, you have to specify it in your hibernate configuration (`hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`) and handle yourself the flush.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on many things and therefore is hard to predict. But I would expect it not to make much of a difference.

You seem to be talking Spring Data JPA here since the question is tagged with `hibernate`. Assuming your transaction spans all the calls to `save`, saving really just adds the entity to the `EntityManager` without actually accessing the database. And when finally a flush happens (typically at the end of the transaction), all entities will get persisted to the database in one go by Hibernate.

Therefore performance differences come from the different code paths in your code and in Spring Data. Those differences should be neglectable from anything coming from actually persisting entities.

If we are talking about huge numbers of entities the performance characteristics of the `EntityManager` itself might become relevant.

If every call to `save` creates its own transaction single calls will most likely be much slower.

So in the end, it boils down to:

Why don't you just try it with your data? And let us know the results?

Answer (score 1):

In case of the list with more than one element, the first approach will be much faster (if the list is has just one element, it should be the same)

Just briefly describing the reason why. During batch insert you will not have the overhead of multiple connection established with single insert multiple time.

Comment: Could you describe it in details? I don't belive that every use of save method makes new connection to database. It may happen in poorly written JDBC code, but hibernate has a connection pool. Especially after reading two other answers I don't belive in yours.